# TableView relationship logic using Parse

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have two table views, one that contains users and one that contains friends. 
How do i make a connection between those two? For example, if i i would press a button on that specific user it would add the user to my friend list and is stored on the Phone rather than on Parse.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Foundation

class AddFriendViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myFriendSearchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet var myFriendSearchList: UITableView!
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()



var searchResult = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Nexa Rust Script L", size: 25)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

    myFriendSearchBar.delegate = self
    myFriendSearchList.delegate = self
    myFriendSearchList.dataSource = self






    self.navigationItem.title = "Haffla"
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }


 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func returnDiss(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
 {
    return searchResult.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1

    myCell.myLabel.text = searchResult[indexPath.row]

    return myCell

}






func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    myFriendSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    let userName:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
   userName.whereKey("username", containsString: searchBar.text)
    userName.limit = 1
    userName.orderByAscending("username")




    userName.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


        if error != nil {

            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)


            myAlert.addAction(okAction)

            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)




            return
        }
        if let friends = objects as [PFObject]? {
            self.searchResult.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for object in friends {


                let username = object.objectForKey("username") as! String
                self.searchResult.append(username)


            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.myFriendSearchList.reloadData()
                self.myFriendSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }

        }



    }

}






func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    myFriendSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    myFriendSearchBar.text? = ""
}



}
```

Edit 1: Added tableview code for the TableView that you can search for people in that database.

Comment: Add some code you have now

Comment: check the edit, i added some code. @alex_p

Comment: As i can see you have no the secondViewController where you need to trasfare the data. Or you have it but not add?

Comment: I have a secondviewController that contains a tableView, when i press on a button in the cell on the firstTableViewController i want it to send that cell to the secondViewController tableView for both users.@alex_p

Comment: Then you only need to update your `dataModel` on your `secondViewController` and call `reloadData` for `tableView` inside it. You show your `secondViewController` after the button pressed on the first one?  Or the `secondViewController` is a `rootViewController` for first and when you push the button on firstViewController it dissmissed and you return back to `secondViewController`?

Comment: I got the `secondViewController` connected to another `rootViewController`. `firstViewController` is connected to another `rootViewController`. What should i send to the `secondViewController`? **myCell** which contains the username or something else?

Comment: in your search controller you have `searchResult` array that in fact is `dataModel` for your `tableView` and you create cells with text from this array. In your `secondController` you probably have another array and create your cells objects with data that contains inside this array. And all you need to do is send searched `String` object from array in your `searchController` to your `secondController` then add this `String` object to your array in `secondController` and `reloadData`

Comment: Alright thanks :) @alex_p